# Swift: How can I solve the error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I want to eliminate an element of my array with an action swipe.
But at the time of sliding the app:

// Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

This is how the error is presented:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIPNT.png)

This is added the element:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnDRI.png)

Main ViewController.

```swift
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  arregloUnidimensional
//
//  Created by Leonardo Rubio on 10/06/22.
//

import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    //MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var fieldNombre:UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var fieldSueldo:UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var butonRegistrar:UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView:UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelPromedio:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelSueldosMayores:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonFinish:UIButton!
    
    //MARK: - Private
    private var arrayDatos = [DataModel]()
    private var counter:Int = 1
    private var attempts:Int = 1
    private var salaries = [Double]()
    private var average:Double = Double()
    private var higherSalaries = [Double]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        
        //Labells.
        customizeLabel(anyLabel: self.labelPromedio)
        customizeLabel(anyLabel: self.labelSueldosMayores)
        //Buttons.
        customizeButton(anyButton: self.butonRegistrar)
        customizeButton(anyButton: self.buttonFinish)
        
    }
    
    //MARK: - Actions
    
    @IBAction func accionRegistrar(_ sender:UIButton){
        validacion()
        self.labelPromedio.text = "Promedio: \(Double(calculateAverage()))"
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func finishAction(_ sender:UIButton){
        if self.arrayDatos.count > 1{
            if self.attempts <= 1{
                self.labelSueldosMayores.text = "Sueldos: \(sueldosM())"
                self.attempts += 1
                self.fieldNombre.text = ""
                self.fieldSueldo.text = ""
            }
        }else{
            showAlert(titulo: "", mensaje: "No es posible promediar, ingresa mas datos.")
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: - Methods
    
    private func showAlert(titulo:String,mensaje:String){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: titulo, message: mensaje, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Aceptar", style: .default))
        present(alert, animated: true)
    }
    
    private func isNumber(text:String)->Bool{
        if Int(text) != nil{
            return true
        }else{
            return false
        }
    }
    
    private func validacion (){
        if let nombre = self.fieldNombre.text{
            if let sueldo = self.fieldSueldo.text{
                if self.counter <= 3{
                    let isNumber = isNumber(text: sueldo)
                    if isNumber{
                        if nombre != ""{
                            let empleado = DataModel(nombre: nombre, sueldo: Int(sueldo))
                            self.salaries.append(Double(sueldo)!)
                            self.arrayDatos.append(empleado)
                            print(self.arrayDatos)
                            self.counter += 1
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                            self.fieldNombre.text = ""
                            self.fieldSueldo.text = ""
                        }else{
                            showAlert(titulo: "", mensaje: "Ingresa un nombre.")
                        }
                    }else{
                        showAlert(titulo: "", mensaje: "Ingresa una cantidad valida. '\(sueldo)' no es una cantidad.")
                    }
                }else{
                    showAlert(titulo: "Alto", mensaje: "El limite de elementos es: \(3)")
                }
            }
        }else{
            showAlert(titulo: "", mensaje: "Ingresa un nombre.")
        }
    }
    
    private func calculateAverage() -> Double{
        self.average = 0
        var suma = 0.0
        for cantidad in self.salaries{
            suma += cantidad
        }
        self.average = suma / Double(self.salaries.count)
        return self.average
    }
    
    private func sueldosM() -> [Double]{
        for cantidad in self.salaries{
            if cantidad > self.average{
                self.higherSalaries.append(cantidad)
            }
        }
        return self.higherSalaries
    }
    
    private func customizeLabel(anyLabel:UILabel){
        anyLabel.layer.cornerRadius = anyLabel.frame.size.height/5.0
        anyLabel.layer.masksToBounds = false
        anyLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGray6.cgColor
        anyLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        anyLabel.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25).cgColor
        anyLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
        anyLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        anyLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
    }
    private func customizeButton(anyButton:UIButton){
        anyButton.layer.cornerRadius = anyButton.bounds.height / 5.0
        anyButton.clipsToBounds = false
        anyButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25).cgColor
        anyButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
        anyButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        anyButton.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
    }
    
    
}

//MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

extension ViewController:UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.arrayDatos.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CustomCell else{
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        if !self.arrayDatos.isEmpty{
            let empleado = self.arrayDatos[indexPath.row]
            cell.llenarEtiquetas(empleado: empleado,index: indexPath.row)
        }
        return cell
    }
}

//MARK: - UITableViewDragDelegate

extension ViewController:UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
            let item = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Eliminar") {  (contextualAction, view, boolValue) in
                
                self.arrayDatos.remove(at: indexPath.row)
   
            }
            let swipeActions = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [item])
        
            return swipeActions
        }
}
```

Any help is welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Please add code instead of images

Comment: This is basic logical error where it simply suggests you tried to get the element from the index which is not available.

Comment: provide full controller code

Comment: I already uploaded the complete code :@Zeeshan Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

In `extension ViewController`, you could try replacing `self.arrayDatos.remove(at: indexPath.row)` with

```
if indexPath.row < self.arrayDatos.count && !(indexPath.row < 0) {
    self.arrayDatos.remove(at: indexPath.row)
}
```

Do the same wherever you use `self.arrayDatos` and `indexPath.row` as an index.

Comment: It doesn't work, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: well that's what you need, to remove an item from your `self.arrayDatos`, **only** if it exist and without crashing your app. Does your app still crash with my example code? Print the `indexPath.row` and the `self.arrayDatos.count` and it will show you why "....it just doesn't do anything."

Comment: Cell is removed from the view but not from the array.
Already and printed the values of indexPath.row and of
arrayData.count.
both give 0

Comment: `...indexPath.row and of arrayData.count. both give 0`, tells you exactly what is wrong.
Your array does not contain the `DataModel`, that your view displays. That is precisely 
what my code is there to protect your app from. You cannot delete an item in an array 
that does not exist at the given index. With my code example your app will not crash.
To remove the `cell` from the view **and** in the `arrayData`, make sure 
your cell displays the same data as in `arrayData`. If `arrayData.count` is zero, it means the data is not there, it has been removed previously or was never there.